# A single-word for “creating public disorder”

Tags: word-request, legalese

What is the noun for creating a serious public disturbance such as being in a gang of thugs who fight among themselves or for acts of abusive and/or violent behaviour in public spaces?

The word **assault** does not fit because it is also used when the physical attack only occurs between two people. For example, ‘*He later pleaded guilty to assaulting a police officer and was sentenced to one day in jail.*’

I looked under Lexico's [synonyms for assault](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/assault) and didn't find what I was looking for.

> John Q is accused of ________

Comment: Reason for the downvote? Lack of research? Lack of detail? The question is not useful? It is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [*affray*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affray) may be the term you want.

*In many legal jurisdictions related to English common law, affray is a public order offence consisting of the fighting of one or more persons in a public place to the terror (in French: à l'effroi) of ordinary people.*

Comment: How about quoting a few lines from the wikipedia page, that way I'll accept your answer?

Comment: Done. Glad to know it _is_ the term you want.